# LC-3 Conditionals (New to this) Just looking for guidance, or answers

Tags: if-statement, lc3

I have to write a program that asks for 3 positive numbers (less than 10). Then output the largest and smallest number. I feel like I'm at a dead end, and have no idea what to do next. Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
.ORIG x3000
LEA R0, MyNameID    ;Show name and ID
PUTS

LEA R0, EnterNum1   ;Print enter number 1
PUTS
GETC R1
OUT

LEA R0, EnterNum2   ;Print enter number 2
PUTS
GETC R2
OUT

LEA R0, EnterNum3   ;Print enter number 3
PUTS
GETC R3
OUT

halt     

MyNameID .STRINGZ "\nName, ID number: "
EnterNum1 .STRINGZ "\nPlease enter number 1:"
EnterNum2 .STRINGZ "\nPlease enter number 2:"
EnterNum3 .STRINGZ "\nPlease enter number 3:"
SmallestNum .STRINGZ "\nThe smallest number is:"
LargestNum .STRINGZ "\nThe largest number is:"
.end
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to negate one of those registers by flipping the bits and then adding one. Then if you add that negated value to another of your numbers in a register, the sum will be zero if they are equal in value ( before the negation). Or the sum will be positive if the second number is bigger. Or the sum will be negative if the first number is negative.  Use BRz BRnand BRp to branch jump to appropriate labels. From there compare the same negated number with your third number using the same addition process. This way you can determine which value is largest and which is smallest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not one of the registers, lets say R1
2. Then add 1 to R1(This essentially makes that register the negative value of the original value)
3. Now add that value to one of the other two registers, lets say R2
4. BR that value to see if its negative
   a. If its negative then R1 is bigger, so have your code skip steps 5-6
5. BR for zero
   a. If its zero then they are equal, so have your code skip steps 6
6. Br for positive
   a. If its positive R2 is bigger, so have your code continue from here
7. Now just repeat the steps with the other registers till you have just one then output it!